# Spring Data Mongo to convert Joda LocaDateTime

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using the Joda `LocalDateTime` and the default behavior of converting to Mongo BSON ended with something like this:

```
"myTime":{
   "iLocalMillis":1327144433115,
   "iChronology":{
      "_class":"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology",
      "iBase":{
         "_class":"org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology",
         "iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4
      }
   }
}
```

This will have the issue when converting back to java objects.

How do I change the behavior for certain java Types when saving to Mongo? since I have several other classes have the same issue with the default converting.

I am using spring 3.1 +data + mongo stack.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. But there are several things not clear: 1) even if only one object need rewriting, then we need to re-define the whole entity; 2) it does not respect the JPA lifecycle annotations using the mongoTemplate. do we have a JPA one? 3) I am using java config for spring 3.1 and have not figured out how to put the converter in afterMappingMongoConverterCreation().

Answer (score 1):

The usage of custom converters is documented in [the reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters).

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. To use Oliver's converter solution I have to create converter for every class has jodatime attribute which is bit annoying. I can't find how to config  converter for a particular type cross all domain classes. I end up with creating a subclass of AbstractMongoEventListener then reset the datetime field before save and after load. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Oliver pointed out, use custom converters.  Watch out for the bug descrbied in [DATAMONGO-1026](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1026).  That issue also has examples of custom converters, and will hopefully be closed soon.